# HQL query joining two domains that know nothing about one another

Tags: grails, hql, grails-orm

My domain model includes several domain classes like so:

[image: Domain model]

The Budget and Employee classes each know about a Position, but the Position class has no knowledge about the Budget or Employee classes. I would like to use GORM to do a query where I get back a list of Budgets and their associated Employees.

I have resorted to using HQL, since it doesn't look like there is a way to use a Criteria query across domains. My query looks like

```
from Budget as budget, Employee as employee where budget.position = employee.position
```

The problem with this query is that there is not a one-to-one mapping from Employees to Positions. That is, there can be Positions "floating" out there where no Employee is assigned to that Position. And a given floating position can be assigned to a Budget but not to an Employee.

I would like to use a left outer join in HQL, something like

```
from Budget as budget left outer join Employee as employee on employee.position = budget.position
```

But it looks like HQL only supports doing joins on properties that are directly on the domain classes. Neither Budget nor Employee knows about one another, so I'm not sure if this is possible. Is there a way to do the query I want in HQL?

Answer (score 0):

Can you modify the domain class definition in grails for Position as such to let gorm know about the association?

```
Position {
    static hasMany = [budgets:Budget, employees:Employee]

}
```

Then you can do and hql statment like such:

```
from Budget b left join b.position p where p.employees is not empty
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't have the authority to modify the relationships on the domain classes, so this won't work for me. Thank you for the idea, though.

Comment: What you could do is write sql itself and invoke that i.e Budget.executeQuery("....")                http://grails.org/doc/latest/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html

Comment: that looks like it still executes HQL and not raw SQL, so I believe this would suffer from the same join restrictions as I mentioned in my question.